# What to do when rubygems.org is down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I have to setup a rails project and rubygems.org is seemed to be down. That's really horrible. Can't believe it the whole ruby community have only one single not-so-reliable gems source. What should I do in such case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best *short* term thing you can do is set your Gemfile's source to:

`source 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org'`

which is our CloudFront distribution URL. I would switch back to rubygems.org though once we're back.

In general, I agree with you. It sucks. We're working on making it better.

Comment: Thanks for the url. Rubygems.org is back now.

Comment: Yes, I wrote RubyGems.org and I head up the maintenance of the site. Not sure what else you want me to prove ;)

Comment: I get the same errors on a 'bundle install' with this distribution URL.

Comment: Cloudfront now has free SSL, via SNI, so this can be updated to a SSL URL.